# Stop form validating on first error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using CI 3.1.7 and want to stop validating form if there is an error. For example:

```
$config = array(
    array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => '%s is required',
            ),
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => '%s is required',
            ),
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => '%s is required',
            ),
    )
);
```

When user leaves *username* and *email* blank, the form will show only *username is required*. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Either you have to validate rule one by one in loop  and throw error instead of full array, or hide errors using css except first one using ex : `.error-class{ display:none; } .error-class:nth-child(1){ display:block; }`

Comment: I'm finding a non-javascript way. If I only use css, I can't (or I haven't known how) choose exactly .error-class to display

Comment: You want it to list all errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question right .. you want to stop on the first encountered form validation error then you have to edit the core form validation library which is extremely bad practice but luckily you can extend its functionality and either edit the `run()` method itself or create your own method and just copy the `run()` code and edit this block of code:

```
    // Execute validation rules
    foreach ($this->_field_data as $field => &$row)
    {
        // Don't try to validate if we have no rules set
        if (empty($row['rules']))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $this->_execute($row, $row['rules'], $row['postdata']);

        // here is the modification
        if(count($this->_error_array) > 0) return true; // error found
    }
```

now it will stop execution when finding its first error

Comment: @Kien Pham try this one, it should stop executing immediately after the first error .. but create your own library and make it extend ci form validation library and modify the run method.

Comment: Your solution won't work since __execute_ method does the validation. I've tried it

Comment: Yeah i know that `_execute` method does the actual validation but according to a foreach loop inside `run` and that's where we wanna stop after the first return from `_execute` after finding the first error.

Comment: Sorry, I tested it again and it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop `validation->run()` but you can control which error message displays. The limitation is you cannot show the error next to the related field. Or, I should say instead, I cannot think of an easy way to show the error next to the input it belongs to.

Anyway, here's how to extract the first error message.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
    // There could be many but grab only the first
    $fields = array_keys($errors);
    $err_msg = $errors[$fields[0]];
}
```

If you want the name of the field you can use this.

```
$err_field = $fields[0];
```

Comment: I have a way to show the error message next/below its input field .. you can return the error_array and using js/jquery you can loop throw that array with its keys equivalent to input names then append the error next to its input field or if you are using bootstrap addClass is-invalid to the input and show the error in .invalid-feedback

Comment: Yeah you can generate it the same way and send it to the view and reload the whole form or spread the load between php and js .. extra flexability

Comment: @SherifSalah I thought like you and used a custom _error_array_. But the thing I really want is to stop executing form validation immediately. Seems haven't any good way yet.

Answer (score -1):

Pleas check

```
  public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // load form and url helpers
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        // load form_validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }
```

Or check https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-form-validation-from-start-to-finish--cms-28768